# How to style focused text fields in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I am globally changing the font in my iOS 7 app with the following:

```
[[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat-Regular" size:15.0]];
```

This changes the font of all text fields. When a text field **receives focus**, however, it changes back to the default Helvetica. Upon losing focus, it is back to the custom font.

Any ideas how to style the text fields when they are in a focused state?

Comment: `UILabel` has no properties than can be set via `appearance`.

Comment: Well... it's definitely working for me :) XCode doesn't show a warning either. But, perhaps there is a better way to do it that wouldn't cause my focus issue?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I figured it out. I needed to use this instead/in addition...

```
[[UITextField appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat-Regular" size:15.0]];
```